# Callout Touch Event

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom MKAnnotationView which I have customised according to the documentation of [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW30).

Here's my code for AnnotationView with Custom Callout view.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == nil && self.selected) {
        CGPoint pointInAnnotationView = [self.superview convertPoint:point toView:self];
        hitView = [self.calloutView hitTest:pointInAnnotationView withEvent:event];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected) {
        CGRect annotationViewBounds = self.bounds;
        CGRect calloutViewFrame = self.calloutView.frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Center the callout view above and to the right of the annotation view.
        calloutViewFrame.origin.x = -(calloutViewFrame.size.width - annotationViewBounds.size.width) * 0.5;
        calloutViewFrame.origin.y = -calloutViewFrame.size.height + 1.0;
        self.calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;
        self.calloutView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        self.calloutView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        [self.calloutView setupCalloutView:self.info];

        [self addSubview:self.calloutView];
    } else {
        [self.calloutView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

I have a button in custom callout view where I am not getting touch action. But I am getting hitTest event of Custom Callout View.

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}
```

So what is the correct way of getting touch event in custom callout view to open detail view controller.

Comment: Check whether user interaction enabled or not and event touchupinside

Comment: @bhoomi it is enabled.